# Quarkus Reactive Messaging RabbitMQ in status "Preview"

Tags: rabbitmq, quarkus, smallrye-reactive-messaging

I have a question concerning the status of the Reactive Messaging RabbitMQ extension, because it is set to be in "Preview", which raises some questions in my company: Do you think there could be features that could be changed in the near future because of this "Preview" status?
Because it seems to rely heavily on Smallrye Reactive Messaging Rabbitmq, which is apparently stable (as there are no warnings on the site and it is a version 3.*). The custom features seem to be related to dev-ui only, and perhaps just the passing of credentials? Do you think there is a high risk of incompatible changes (outside dev-ui, let's say) in the future?

In addition, do you have an idea of when this status would be changed to "Stable"?

Thank you

Comment: This might be something which is better asked in an issue on GitHub: https://github.com/quarkusio/quarkus/issues?q=is%3Aopen+is%3Aissue+label%3Aarea%2Freactive-messaging,area%2Fsmallrye

Comment: Thanks, I don't know, because I was redirected to stackoverflow from Github when creating an issue of type "Question" in Quarkus :-)

Comment: For general product usage questions, Stack Overflow is definitely the right place. For a project management task about the timing/stability of the next release, only the project maintainers can answer it, so Stack Overflow probably isn't the right place.

Comment: Indeed, thanks. I have opened a discussion here: https://github.com/quarkusio/quarkus/discussions/39632